# Problema em montar uma matriz em C

Tags: c, matriz, ascii

Estou com um problema com uma matriz que montei para seja digitado letras e estas transformadas em números da tabela ascii, mas ela não imprime
Onde estou errando? Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
 char i, j, m[3][3];
 char tecla[0];


 //captura os elementos
 for(i=0;i<3;i++)
 for(j=0;j<3;j++){
 printf("Elemento[%d][%d]= ",i,j);
 tecla[0] = getche();
 scanf("%c",&m[i][j]);
 }
 //EXIBIR VALORES ORIGINAIS
 printf("\n::: Valores Originais :::\n");
 for(i=0;i<3;i++){
 for(j=0;j<3;j++)
 printf("%c ",m[i][j]);
 tecla[0] = getche();
 printf("\n");
 }
```

Comment: Tem certeza que deseja criar um vetor de tamanho zero?

Comment: Observe os `{` e `}` desses laços `for`. Parece estar errado.

Comment: Queria que as letras digitadas fossem exibidas no final, e isso não acontece, mesmo com a mudança sugerida por vocês

Comment: O meu código somente apresenta a última letra digitada

Comment: @WilliamHenrique Não "corrija" a identação de perguntas onde os problemas de identação são parte do problema da pergunta!

Comment: @VictorStafusa blz mano! obrigado pelo toque!

Answer (score 3):

Acho que o que você queria era isso:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    char i, j, m[3][3];
    char tecla;

    //captura os elementos
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("Elemento[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
            tecla = getche();
            scanf("%c", &m[i][j]);
         }
     }

     //EXIBIR VALORES ORIGINAIS
     printf("\n::: Valores Originais :::\n");
     for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
         for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
             printf("%c ", m[i][j]);
         }
         printf("\n");
     }
     tecla = getche();
}
```

Sempre use o `{` e o `}` para evitar cometer erros. Por exemplo, nesse código que você postou:

```
 //EXIBIR VALORES ORIGINAIS
 printf("\n::: Valores Originais :::\n");
 for(i=0;i<3;i++){
 for(j=0;j<3;j++)
 printf("%c ",m[i][j]);
 tecla[0] = getche();
 printf("\n");
 }
```

Observe que o `for` de dentro não tem o `{`. Isso faz com que o `tecla[0] = getche();` e o `printf("\n");` estejam fora do `for` interno. Se você sempre usar o `{` em todos os laços `for`, não terá esse problema. Identar tudo de forma adequada também te ajudará bastante.

Além disso, `char tecla[0];` declara um array de zero posições e você escreve na primeira posição dele (a posição 0), que já está fora do array. Isso não faz sentido, é mais fácil usar apenas uma variável comum `char tecla;`.

Comment: Infelizmente fui eu que indentei mal lol, muito devido à forma confusa como haviam `{` e `}` em falta. Vou dar um jeito, mas não invalida o uso muito aconselhado de `{` `}` claro.

Comment: @Isac É por causa de situações como essa que criei isso: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6300/132

Comment: Eu percebo de facto o seu ponto de vista mas é bem difícil ler o código todo corrido sem nenhuma indentação, dai que tenha indentado. Na maior parte dos casos não afeta interpretação mas neste de fato afetou. Podemos sempre retroceder nas edições e voltar ao estado não indentado e reaplicar o ajuste de tags

Comment: @Isac Sim, claro. Mas eu sempre sou extremamente conservador em relação a editar o código da pergunta porque já vi inúmeros casos onde identar direito é parte da resposta.

Comment: Sim concordo. Irei seguir o conselho e ser bem mais conservador no que toca edições de código.